# AWS SDK 2.x DynamoDB DocumentAPI

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I can't seem to figure out what have AWS done with all their SDK versions. I want access to the functionality from DynamoDB Document API, like `QuerySpec` classes, yet when I add dependency to the [current latest AWS SDK](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/dynamodb/2.10.56) I can't find the `dynamodbv2` namespace in the package, on the other hand if I use [older 1.11.x SDK](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-dynamodb/1.11.713) I have the Document API and `dynamodbv2` namespace available.

What is going on and why all those version numbers are mismatched? Which version should I use in a non-legacy project?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually we had to contact AWS support to get clear answers:

> The AWS SDK for Java 2.0 is now generally available and supported for
>   production use. The 2.0 version of the SDK is a major rewrite of the
>   1.11 code base. Built for support for Java 8+, The AWS SDK for Java 2.0 adds several frequently requested features, like support for non-blocking I/O, better start-up performance and automatic iteration
>   over paginated responses. In addition to these new features, many
>   aspects of the SDK have been refactored with a strong focus on
>   consistency, immutability, and ease of use.
>
> However, some of the high-level libraries, such as the Amazon S3
>   transfer manager and the Amazon DynamoDB mapper, are not yet available
>   in version 2.x.